# Google Maps Native App - Map Links

Tags: url, google-maps, geolocation, mobile-website

I want to open the native google maps application on a mobile device from my mobile website.  Currently I am using the URL http://maps.google.com/maps?q=The%20Diner,%2027%20Main%20Street,%20The%20Village%20@55.7665863,-4.1455545, which works for one location.

What I am looking to do is show multiple locations with a different coloured marker.  Is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well i found when you use the non-secure url and post a list of postcodes it works fine you can add more postcodes by adding another +to: ;

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=embed&saddr=LD7+1EN&daddr=CH1+3AE+to:AB12+3AX&

havent really tried to make it do different markers with different colors or anything, but i suggest looking at the url generated by your browser in google maps and ensuring its not a https:/ link and i think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use google static maps in place of what you have?

This page shows a [static map example with multiple markers](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Comment: Thanks Libby but its a dynamic map loading in the native google app that I really want.  The static is my last resort.