# Is there away to start a phones native Navigation tool from Flex 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5, air-android

I am building a mobile application in Flex 4.5 and from this app I would like to start the device's native navigation tool, like Google Navigation for example.

Is there a way to open the Navigation App using Flex 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I knew, there was no way to launch other applications from a mobile Flex App.

Some native apps can be opened using URLs.  It is, basically, the Flash Platform version of saying "Let the OS Handle it."  If you HTTP link to a video, for example, it may open in a native player or it may open in the browser.

You can open the native text messaging program using [sms as the protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787905/sms-url-on-android).  As far as I know, there is no universal URL to open navigation services.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470631/google-maps-native-app-map-links) alludes to the fact that linking to maps.google.com will do it.

You can look into using the [AIR Geolocation services](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_as_geolocation_api.html) APIs; but that is intended for in-app usage not launching other apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) to open up google maps or something.  I don't think there's a way to open the native navigation app because it might not be there and they're different for each device.